# Stream video via Airplay, change lockscreen title & album art?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video

My app grabs a m3u8 playlist and plays the video, streaming over AirPlay works, too. The only thing that bugs me is that it shows the full URL as the video title on the lockscreen and in ControlCenter. Is there any way to change this? I've tried MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.